# SQL why use 'between' instead of '>= and <='

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sap-ase

I'd like to understand any differences in using 'where num between 2 and 4' and 'where num >= 2 and num <= 4', as it applies to Oracle, Sybase-ASE and MSSQL.

From purely visual perspective, "between" looks better to me.
However I'm more worried about performance and any other technical issues. (for example is it possible for execution plan to be different)

Is 'between' a purely cosmetic keyword? to avoid having the 'and', or does it offer something more?

Comment: `a between b and c` is syntactic sugar for `(b <= a and a <= c)`.  It's just for convenience.

Comment: @SilentByte, between does cover 2 and 4.

Comment: Simple answer: because it is available and you have to type less.

Comment: In SQL Server 2000 `BETWEEN` used to have an advantage in preventing double evaluation of sub queries but [no longer the case](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2008/06/27/subqueries-in-between-and-case-statements.aspx)

Comment: BETWEEN would prevent the need to fetch `a` twice.  Probably no big deal in "smart" SQL implementations, but may be not trivial in some less smart ones.

Comment: This is a very difficult question to answer because in some platforms BETWEEN is just syntactic sugar, but I don't know if anybody can provide a single authoritative answer that represents *all* platforms accurately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes using `BETWEEN` can save you from evaluating an operation more than once:

```
SELECT  AVG(RAND(20091225) BETWEEN 0.2 AND 0.4)
FROM    t_source;

---
0.1998

SELECT  AVG(RAND(20091225) >= 0.2 AND RAND(20091225) <= 0.4)
FROM    t_source;

---
0.3199
```

In the first query `RAND()` is only called once, but in the second query `RAND` is called twice, here `BETWEEN` saves you a second function call to `RAND`.

There is also something to be said for readability in SQL queries, queries can become *massive*, functions like `BETWEEN` help improve this.

Answer (score 2):

The database optimized queries, and should have the same performance either way.

That is, the optimizer will create a parse tree, and the two should have the same execution plan.